# Installing pear on Mac Yosemite

Tags: pear

I'm trying to install pear on Mac Yosemite. but not sure how to do that. I don't use mamp or xampp. I'm using built in Apache and php but it doesn't have pear.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/ and http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-pear-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx10-810-7/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple google search tells what to do.

Comment: ```brew install php56 --with-pear```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)?

```
brew install php56 --with-pear
```

In case the binary is still not there, try link it via:

```
brew unlink php56 && brew link php56 --dry-run && brew link php56
```

Comment: It does not have pear on it's own.

Comment: This should help before `brew tap homebrew/science`.